# VimTeX: Viewer cannot find Zathura window ID! (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS x11)

Tags: neovim, plugin-vimtex, linux-ubuntu

The PDF file is not opening with Zathura after the VimTeX compilation. I am using https://github.com/benbrastmckie/.config and the file `vimtex.lua` in my directory  `~/.config/nvim/lua/neotex/plugins` contains:

```
return {
  "lervag/vimtex",
  init = function()
    vim.g['vimtex_view_method'] = 'zathura'        -- main variant with xdotool (requires X11; not compatible with wayland)
    -- vim.g['vimtex_view_method'] = 'zathura_simple' -- for variant without xdotool to avoid errors in wayland
    vim.g['vimtex_quickfix_mode'] = 0              -- suppress error reporting on save and build
    vim.g['vimtex_mappings_enabled'] = 0           -- Ignore mappings
    vim.g['vimtex_indent_enabled'] = 0             -- Auto Indent
    vim.g['tex_flavor'] = 'latex'                  -- how to read tex files
    vim.g['tex_indent_items'] = 0                  -- turn off enumerate indent
    vim.g['tex_indent_brace'] = 0                  -- turn off brace indent
    vim.g['vimtex_context_pdf_viewer'] = 'okular'  -- external PDF viewer run from vimtex menu command
    vim.g['vimtex_log_ignore'] = ({                -- Error suppression:
      'Underfull',
      'Overfull',
      'specifier changed to',
      'Token not allowed in a PDF string',
    })
  end,
}
```

Initially, I was trying with `vim.g['vimtex_view_method'] = 'zathura_simple'` as being used in the [repository](https://github.com/benbrastmckie/.config/blob/4f065d1f313ae7c2aeb04061aa1e6faa63a85229/nvim/lua/neotex/plugins/vimtex.lua). In that case, neither the error showed up nor Zathura opened the PDF.

**Update:**

I just figured VimTeX couldn't open the PDF through Zathura because my working directory name had a colon (:) symbol. For example, if the PDF file `main.pdf` is in the directory `~/Documents/testing test`, I can open it:

```
zathura '~/Documents/testing test/main.pdf'
```

But my folder name was `testing: test` and in that case, it wasn't opening with Zathura:

```
zathura '~/Documents/testing: test/main.pdf'
```

Is there any way to fix it? Or is it recommended not to put a colon in the folder or directory names?